# Why are there not mnemonic-seed words in Turkish especially considering the increasing rate of bitcoin adoption in the country?

Tags: mnemonic-seed, seed

[image]How come bitcoin doesn't have Turkish words as wallet seeds especially considering the increasing rate of bitcoin adoption in the country ?

Answer (score 5):

Because no one has stepped up to do the work or hire someone to do it for them. That's how open source works : )

[This repository](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/tree/master/bip-0039) contains the mnemonic list in different languages (Currently just 8). There are also wordlists [in other languages](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/pulls?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Apr+is%3Aopen+wordlist) that are [stuck in limbo](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/pull/863#issuecomment-559024471). However if you find it to be worth it, you might want to prepare a list and submit it to the repository as a pull request, and one day it might get merged.

Comment: Will do for sure.

Comment: @EfeCini And that's the open source spirit! I'm sure it'll prove useful and be incorporated in a wallet software one day. You may also try submitting it to other repositories such as Trezor's here: https://github.com/trezor/python-mnemonic/tree/master/mnemonic/wordlist

Comment: Yes open source rocksbut earning shitty fiat by working on bitcoin would be great too tbh. Should I also submit it to other wallets like ledger,coldcard too?

Comment: Of course. And I wish you luck, some might not be able to accept because they wouldn't know any speakers of that language to review your wordlist. In that case, you may ask them if instead you could ask for a review in the BitcoinTalk forums. It has a Turkish section if I recall correctly. Then you could address the points raised and they should be able to accept.

Comment: I couldn't understand the part "_BIP39's authors have abandoned the BIP_" Also how many people have access to merge BIPs or changes in BIPs? Even I suggested a small change few weeks back which got ACKs as well but still pending to be merged.

Comment: All these people (https://github.com/orgs/bitcoin/people) can accept changes. The main maintainer (The BIP Editor) is luke-jr, so maybe you could ping him and ask him if there is anything in your changes that he finds doubtful.